# NPM Install fails for chromedriver and selenium-driver in Windows 7

Tags: node.js, selenium, npm, selenium-chromedriver, npm-install

I have a fairly simple package.json which has some dev dependencies in it. It looks like this:

```
"devDependencies": {
   "cssnano": "3.3.2",
   "cucumber": "0.9.2",
   "diff": "2.2.0",
   "grunt": "0.4.5",
   "jit-grunt": "0.9.1",
   "grunt-istanbul": "0.6.1",

   "chromedriver": "^2.20.0",
   "grunt-selenium-webdriver": "^0.2.482",
   "v8-profiler": "5.3.2"
}
```

Initially I had items till grun-istanbul and when I ran NPM Install it worked fine adding all the modules. But when I added the last three items chromedriver, selenium webdriver and v8-profiler then the npm install started failing!! Now I get the below error(I cleaned the cache also but no help). I am using Node 4.2.1 and NPM 3.3.12.

```
C:\DEV2>npm install
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program    Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\nathsubr\\AppDat
a\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install"
npm ERR! node v4.2.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12

npm ERR! shasum check failed for C:\Users\nathsubr\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-10080-
6e86d1c7\10.0.20.149_4873\chromedriver\-\chromedriver-2.21.2.tgz
npm ERR! Expected: f4dab2ab58b35f70209ffcd1d2bc13e26fb2ed64
npm ERR! Actual:   c61a192c95b5cc1e1d8620f1536a4867da3da432
npm ERR! From:       http://10.0.20.149:4873/chromedriver/-/chromedriver-2.21.2.tg
z
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\DEV2\npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

npm cache clean

npm install